# Paypal payout item has status "blocked" - What is the subsequent workflow if any?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We are currently trying to create a payout system with the Paypal REST API. 
Therefore we need to use the [Payout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payouts) specified by Paypal.

There is a section which describes the different states and return codes a payout item can have: [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#get-the-status-of-a-batch-payout)

The one, which is unclear to me is the following:

> BLOCKED - The item is blocked.

The questions are:

1. If a payout item has the state "blocked", does this mean, that the payout will be canceled and the money returned to us - as account owners - or does it mean, that the money was send and our part of the payout was successful and therefore finished?
2. Are there any subsequent workflows? For example: will the state "blocked" be changed after some time to for example "returned", like it happens with "unclaimed" payouts after a month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If a payout item has the state "blocked", does this mean, that the
>    payout will be canceled and the money returned to us - as account
>    owners - or does it mean, that the money was send and our part of the
>    payout was successful and therefore finished?

So far as I know, money will be not be sent and in fact, payment server will not be called because PayPal will run RISK checking first before calling payment server.

> 2. Are there any subsequent workflows? For example: will the state
>    "blocked" be changed after some time to for example "returned", like
>    it happens with "unclaimed" payouts after a month?

Answer same as in (1). Payment server will not be called so no money sent from receiver account.

Comment: so it sounds like if the state is "blocked" then no money moved is that correct? The sender's account's balance should not have changed?

Comment: Yes. Money will not be sent. Balance will remain unchanged

Comment: #2 not really answered. Is BLOCKED an end state or will that status change?